# parameterize a variable in selenium junit to load test a website to run on jmeter

Tags: java, performance, selenium, jmeter, junit4

I need to load test a website that execute XHR objects.
normal load testing can't apply in this case as the load testing looks for the server side of things and I'm interested in the client side.

the only thing i need to parameterize is the username to make the script run concurrently

I did use Katalon Recorder to get the automation code as JUnit then inputted it into selenium then exported it as a jar file  and used it in Jmeter.

the code works for  a single user but i  can't think of a way to get the script to run concurrently

package dashboard;

```
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class Testpage {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Path/To/chromedriver.exe");

      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);


    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test
  public void testDashboard() throws Exception {
    driver.get("https://test.com/newlogin");
    driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).sendKeys("Username");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("Password!");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='LOGIN'])[1]/following::input[3]")).click();
    driver.get("https://test.com");
    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Italy'])[3]/following::td[4]"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    driver.get("https://test.com/1");
    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Guest_Arrivals_CY'])[2]/following::span[1]"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    driver.get("https://test.com/2");
    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Nov 18'])[1]/following::div[4]"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    driver.get("https://test.com/3");
    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.cssSelector("#kSXbjj > svg"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    driver.get("https://test.com/4");
    for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
        try { if (isElementPresent(By.cssSelector("#tGPUB > svg > g > text"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
  }

  private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
      driver.findElement(by);
      return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private boolean isAlertPresent() {
    try {
      driver.switchTo().alert();
      return true;
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
    try {
      Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
      String alertText = alert.getText();
      if (acceptNextAlert) {
        alert.accept();
      } else {
        alert.dismiss();
      }`enter code here`
      return alertText;
    } finally {
      acceptNextAlert = true;
    }
  }
}
```

in its current state the pages load conservatively for a single user as soon as the element in the page gets loaded it moves on the next page and so on

Answer (score 0):

You need to link your script with [ApacheJMeter_core library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_core). This will give you access to [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) class which in its turn provides read/write access to [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) via [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class.

The relevant code would be something like:

```
JMeterVariables vars = JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables();
String username = vars.get("username"); // this will read `${username}` JMeter Variable
```

See [How to Use JUnit With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter) article for more tips and tricks you can play with the [JUnit Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request) sampler.